# How to make up responsive menu bar side by side with search bar on Blogger

Tags: html, css

I have a blog and I want to set the menu bar side by side with search bar.

I successfully coded it and it display very well in desktop or mobile. The problem is when I click to the menu icon (appear in mobile or smaller screen) the search bar goes down. I can't make the search bar stick to its position.

To better understand my problem take a look at the picture link below.

```
this is desktop view - OK
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/--K3PoETimG8/Vvx5QZM__OI/AAAAAAAAEYs/4LScpQH4wwUGLRof0fyh1qPUGhIiXo31QCCo/s912-Ic42/menu%2Bdesktop.jpg

this is responsive view - OK
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-r05X_rR1qzQ/Vvx5i-oP9vI/AAAAAAAAEY0/tWIN_lkqOsE3pwaP3Gd8oBlMaxfCiONtwCCo/s590-Ic42/menu%2Bmobile.jpg

this is responsive view when i click on menu icon - not OK, the search bar should always in top
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-tftYFNr4fls/Vvx5t2Is96I/AAAAAAAAEY0/hD-U7uT3Mo4s2lOzpZf-iw06FNujXV-hwCCo/s581-Ic42/menu%2Bmobile%2B2.jpg
```

this is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {margin:0;}
ul.main-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #193550;

}

ul.main-menu li {float: left;}

ul.main-menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 16px;
}

ul.main-menu li a:hover {background-color: #111;}

ul.main-menu li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.main-menu li:not(:first-child) {display: 

none;}
  ul.main-menu li.icon {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.main-menu.responsive-main-menu {position: 

relative;}
  ul.main-menu.responsive-main-menu li.icon {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.main-menu.responsive-main-menu li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.main-menu.responsive-main-menu li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
#searchbar{float:right; margin:7px 8px 5px 0;}
#searchbar input[type="text"] { -moz-box-sizing: 

border-box;background: #FCFCFC; border: 1px solid 

#DFDFDF; box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04); 

color: #888888; padding: 5px 0; width: 120px; 

transition: all 0.25s linear 0s; text-indent:8px;}
#searchbar button {background:#00a1e0; border:0; 

color: #FFFFFF; cursor:pointer; padding:5px 8px; 

box-shadow:0 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);}
#searchbar button:hover{opacity:0.8;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-

size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰ MENU</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<form action='/search' id='searchbar' method='get'>
<input id='s' name='q' onblur='if (this.value == 

&quot;&quot;) {this.value = &quot;Enter 

keywords&quot;;}' onfocus='if (this.value == 

&quot;Enter keywords&quot;) {this.value = 

&quot;&quot;;}' type='text' value='Enter 

keywords'/>
<button type='submit'><i class='fa fa-

search'/></button>
</form>
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("main-menu")

[0].classList.toggle("responsive-main-menu");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you test position: absolute on the search bar on mobile view with relative position of the .main-menu container ?

Comment: yes, i tried it, but the result is not what i wanted. instead of sticking in up, it move to the far left side

Comment: can you make a JSFiddle of it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div id="top">

    <div class="nav">
    <ul class="main-menu">
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="search">  
    <form></form>
    </div>

    </div>
```

CSS Code

```
.nav {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    }

.search {
    position:relative;
    float: right;
    width:50%;
    }
```

Comment: holy cow, thank you @Javier Gonzalez for the clue, i modify your code and add some z index, and voila it works perfectly what i wanted. thank you everyone too for the help